# Elm 'Json.Decode.succeed': how is it used in a decode pipeline if it is supposed to always return the same value?

Tags: json, elm

I'm learning Elm and one thing that has puzzled me is 'Json.Decode.succeed'.  According to the [docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/json/latest/Json-Decode)

```
succeed : a -> Decoder a

Ignore the JSON and produce a certain Elm value.

decodeString (succeed 42) "true"    == Ok 42
decodeString (succeed 42) "[1,2,3]" == Ok 42
decodeString (succeed 42) "hello"   == Err ...
```

I understand that (although, as a beginner, I don't yet see its use).  But this method is *also* used in a Decode pipeline, thus:

```
somethingDecoder : Maybe Wookie -> Decoder Something
somethingDecoder maybeWookie =
    Json.Decode.succeed Something
        |> required "caterpillar" Caterpillar.decoder
        |> required "author" (Author.decoder maybeWookie)
```

What is going on here?  That is, if 'succeed' ignores the JSON that's passed to it, how is it used to read JSON and turn it into Elm values?  Any clues appreciated!

Comment: @glennsl -- What I mean is this: if the point of Json.Decode is to turn JSON into elm values, and if 'succeed' ignores the JSON that's passed to it, I don't understand how the two mesh.  Do you see what I mean?  When I said 'obvious', what I meant was I see a contradiction here that doesn't exist, but which comes from my ignorance.  I'm not impugning the definition, I'm asking how 'succeed', which ignores JSON, is used to read and transform JSON...

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. Not sure I can explain this simply, as there's a lot of mathy concepts involved here, but I'll try.

Comment: Thanks.  I found this -- https://korban.net/posts/elm/2018-07-10-how-json-decode-pipeline-chaining-works/ -- that says "Json.Decode.succeed...returns a decoder that always produces a particular value", so in my code, the value it's returning is 'Something', which is a function?  And so that is used to fill in the final structure that the pipeline decodes to?  I would appreciate your explanation, as I'm a bit muddled on this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to start, the intuition for a decoder pipeline is that it acts like a curried function where piping with `required` and `optional` applies arguments one-by-one. Expect that everything, both the function, its arguments *and* the return value are all wrapped in `Decoder`s.

So as an example:

```
succeed Something
  |> required (succeed 42)
  |> required (succeed "foo")
```

is equivalent to

```
succeed (Something 42 "foo")
```

and

```
decodeString (succeed (Something 42 "foo")) whatever
```

will return `Ok (Something 42 "foo")` as long as `whatever` is valid JSON.

When everything succeeds it's just a really convoluted function call. The more interesting aspect of decoders, and the reason we use them in the first place, is in the error path. But since 'succeed' is what's of interest here, we'll ignore that and save a lot of time, text and brain cells. Just know that without considering the error path this will all seem very contrived.

Anyway, let's try to recreate this to see how it works.

#### Decode.map2

The key to the pipelines, apart form the pipe operator, is the `Decode.map2` function. You've probably already used it, or its siblings, if you've tried writing JSON decoders without using pipelines. We can implement our example above using `map2` like this:

```
map2 Something
  (succeed 42)
  (succeed "foo")
```

This will work exactly like the example above. But the problem with this, from a user POV, is that if we need to add another argument we also have to change `map2` to `map3`. And also `Something` isn't wrapped in a decoder, which is boring.

#### Calling functions wrapped in Decoders

The reason this is useful anyway is because it gives us access to several values at the same time, and the ability to combine them in whatever way we want. We can use this to call a function inside a `Decoder` with an argument inside a `Decoder` and have the result also wrapped in a `Decoder`:

```
map2 (\f x -> f x)
  (succeed String.fromInt)
  (succeed 42)
```

#### Currying and partial application

Unfortunately this still has the problem of needing to change the `map` function if we need more arguments. If only there was a way to apply arguments to a function one at a time... like if we had currying and partial application. Since we have a way to call functions wrapped in decoders now, what if we return a partially applied function instead and apply the remaining arguments later?

```
map2 (\f x -> f x)
  (succeed Something)
  (succeed 42)
```

will return a `Decoder (string -> Something)`, so now we just have to rinse and repeat with this and the last argument:

```
map2 (\f x -> f x)
  (map2 (\f x -> f x)
    (succeed Something)
    (succeed 42))
  (succeed "")
```

Et voila, we have now recreated JSON decode pipelines! Although it might not look like it on the surface.

#### Ceci n'est pas une pipe

The final trick is to use `map2` with the pipe operator. The pipe is essentially defined as `\x f -> f x`. See how similar this looks to the function we've been using? The only difference is that the arguments are swapped around, so we need to swap the order we pass arguments as well:

```
map2 (|>)
  (succeed "")
  (map2 (|>)
    (succeed 42)
    (succeed Something))
```

and then we can use the pipe operator again to reach the final form

```
succeed Something
  |> map2 (|>)
      (succeed 42)
  |> map2 (|>)
      (succeed "")
```

It should now be apparent that `required` is just an alias for `map2 (|>)`.

And that's all there is to it!

Comment: Thorough explanation glennsl!

It might not be obvious to Elm newcomers `type alias Something = { foo : Int, bar : String }` automatically creates a helper function `Something` with the signature `Int -> String -> Something`.

So `succeed Something` has the signature `Decoder (Int -> String -> Something)`. As you've described above, this get's piped down across some `map2`s to eventually give you a `Decoder Something`. This is also called `apply` in the Haskell÷